# rake: NameError: uninitialized constant Config

Tags: rake

I am installing Redmine and I am getting crazy because of a rake problem. In particular, in order to perform a bundle install for the different Ruby's plugins, I have been asked to install xapian-full-alaveteli, v 1.2.9.5.
The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing xapian-full-alaveteli:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/redmine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -rubygems /home/redmine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/home/redmine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/xapian-full-alaveteli-1.2.9.5 RUBYLIBDIR=/home/redmine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/xapian-full-alaveteli-1.2.9.5
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Config
/home/redmine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/xapian-full-alaveteli-1.2.9.5/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/redmine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/xapian-full-alaveteli-1.2.9.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/redmine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/xapian-full-alaveteli-1.2.9.5/gem_make.out
```

I've tried editing by hand the rakefile and removing the line that causes troubles, but it magically reappears. The documentation about the use of rake/gem is, imho, at least vague, therefore I am totally stuck -- with a server that was supposed to be in production two days ago...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Summary

Obsolete calls to Config can cause the error. Try changing

```
Config::CONFIG    ====>    RbConfig::CONFIG
```

#### In detail

Running a Gem's rakefile caused the error: uninitialized constant Config.

Googling suggests [Config is obsolete and to replace it with RbConfig.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine/issues/7) RbConfig is in the latest Ruby [though the document is blank](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/extmk/rdoc/RbConfig.html) and [I cannot find a Config in Ruby](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ruby+2.4.0+config&oq=ruby+2.4.0+config).

Fixes replace Config with RbConfig:  [gettalong/kramdown](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/pull/345/files) and [thoughtbot/cocaine](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine/commit/06f8ed6da248b5f168d0dd41dbd6c7830d38b907). Which also worked in my case.

#### Conclusion

Replace `Config::CONFIG` with `RbConfig::CONFIG`

Comment: does this also apply to <APP>::CONFIG ?? Seeing the same error after updating to Rails 6. but there's nothing in my project with a ref to Config::CONFIG just MYAPP::CONFIG